# What's wrong with my System.Threading.Tasks.Task usage?

Tags: multithreading, c#-4.0

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public sealed class Foo
{
    public int ID;

    private static readonly Dictionary<int, Foo> Instances = new Dictionary<int, Foo>();

    public static void FillInstances()
    {
        // here's some magic code to fill .Instances
    }

    public static void DoSomething()
    {
        var tasks = new Task[Instances.Count];
        var i = 0;
        foreach (var foo in Instances.Values)
        {
            var instance = foo; // just to break the reference
            var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(instance.DoSomethingInternal);
            tasks[i++] = task;
            Logger.DebugFormat("translation: task #{0} = id {1}", task.Id, instance.ID);
        }
        using (var timer = new Timer(callback =>
        {
            Logger.DebugFormat("--------------------- {0}", DateTime.Now);
            foreach (var task in tasks)
            {
                var taskInstance = task; // just to break the reference
                Logger.DebugFormat("task #{0}: {1}", taskInstance.Id, taskInstance.Status);
            }
        }, null, TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)))
        {
            Task.WaitAll(tasks);
            Logger.Debug("ready");
        }
    }

    private void DoSomethingInternal()
    {
        Logger.DebugFormat("DoSomethingInternal / task #{0} - id {1}", Task.CurrentId, this.ID);
    }
}
```

The itention should be clear: I'm calling a static method `DoSomething` to call instance-methods `DoSomethingInternal` parallel.

To output of my console is:

```
translation: task #1 = id 9
translation: task #2 = id 5
translation: task #3 = id 2
translation: task #4 = id 3
translation: task #5 = id 7
translation: task #6 = id 8
translation: task #7 = id 1
translation: task #8 = id 10
DoSomethingInternal / task #8 - id 10
DoSomethingInternal / task #7 - id 1
DoSomethingInternal / task #6 - id 8
DoSomethingInternal / task #5 - id 7
DoSomethingInternal / task #4 - id 3
--------------------- 12/01/2011 08:29:57
task #1: Running
task #2: Running
task #3: Running
task #4: RanToCompletion
task #5: RanToCompletion
task #6: RanToCompletion
task #7: RanToCompletion
task #8: RanToCompletion
--------------------- 12/01/2011 08:29:58
task #1: Running
task #2: Running
task #3: Running
task #4: RanToCompletion
task #5: RanToCompletion
task #6: RanToCompletion
task #7: RanToCompletion
task #8: RanToCompletion
--------------------- 12/01/2011 08:29:59
task #1: Running
task #2: Running
task #3: Running
task #4: RanToCompletion
task #5: RanToCompletion
task #6: RanToCompletion
task #7: RanToCompletion
task #8: RanToCompletion
```

Obviously task #1, #2, #3 never get started, but `.Status` of this `System.Threading.Tasks.Task`-instances tells us that it's `Running`.
So what's the problem here?

Comment: Cant confirm behaviour on my box, have you tried replacing   Logger.DebugFormat("DoSomethingInternal / task #{0} - id {1}", Task.CurrentId, this.ID); with something simpler. e.g. Debug.Writeline? Maybe your logger does not handle multi-threaded access

Comment: @Dominik i'm using log4net ... but I'll give it a try!

Comment: @Dominik nope, did not change anything ... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say you have a deadlock somewhere in `DoSomethingInternal` your output looks far to linear to me.

When I run your code, using `Console.WriteLine` for both logger methods, the output is:

```
translation: task #1 = id 0
DoSomethingInternal / task #1 - id 0
translation: task #2 = id 1
translation: task #3 = id 2
DoSomethingInternal / task #2 - id 1
DoSomethingInternal / task #3 - id 2
DoSomethingInternal / task #4 - id 3
translation: task #4 = id 3
translation: task #5 = id 4
DoSomethingInternal / task #5 - id 4
DoSomethingInternal / task #6 - id 5
translation: task #6 = id 5
translation: task #7 = id 6
translation: task #8 = id 7
DoSomethingInternal / task #7 - id 6
DoSomethingInternal / task #8 - id 7
translation: task #9 = id 8
translation: task #10 = id 9
DoSomethingInternal / task #10 - id 9
DoSomethingInternal / task #9 - id 8
ready
```

I can get a similar output as you do by locking the same object in `DoSomething` and `DoSomethingInternal` although in my case it is the first 7 which don't complete. *running `DoSomething` on a `ThreadPool` thread*

Comment: the main issue isn't that the methods don't complete, they even not get entered ...

Comment: @Andreas From what I understand, some tasks will be batched onto the same thread. In the case that that thread gets blocked, those tasks will never execute.

Comment: thanks for that input ... but what if I do not have any locks?

Comment: Sorry for my last comment, it didn't make much sense. If you have 4 threads available, One is running DoSomething, the first three tasks will be put onto the other available threads. If something has a lock on the first thread stopping them from entering (maybe even in the logging) they will sit there forever. It appears Task.WaitAll(tasks) will yeild control to a task it is waiting for (since there is no point it doing nothing) thus it goes though the remaining 7 tasks. It can't do this for the first three because they have already been given to other threads.

Comment: Sooo ... your initial idea `some tasks will be batched onto the same thread` hit the nail ... actually my example was scoped in "another task". in this other task i called `static Foo.FooMethod` but actually was doing the work in `cctor`. this broke the chain - somehow the new `ThreadPool` is waiting explicitely for `static Foo.FooMethod` (which has no code inside) - but the work is done in `cctor Foo`... thanks buddy for this hint!